# Select element by class name issue

Tags: jquery

I have a question regarding the `Jquery` selector.

I have an `element class` like the following

```
<td class='test color-picker'>cell</td>
```

I tried to select it with `$('.test color-picker')` but it doesn't seem to be able to select when there is a space between them. I can't change the class name because it effects so many other things. Are there anyways I can go around it? Thanks so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('.test.color-picker')
```

This will match an element with **both** classes.  `class='test color-picker'` is 2 distinct class names, `test` and `color-picker`.

Your code was trying to find a `<color-picker>` element contained within an element with the class of `test`.

Comment: Probably worth noting that this syntax works the same way for css as well.  A good understanding of css selectors is helpful when using jquery.

Answer (score 2):

Do not put a space:

```
$('.test.color-picker')
```

Your current code assumes that your html looks like this:

```
<td class='test'>
    <color-picker></color-picker>
</td>
```

Which is not the case.

Answer (score 1):

Since your want to find the element having both class, so instead of space,use like this:

```
$('.test.color-picker')
```

For more reference : read the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/)

Answer (score 0):

jQuery uses the [Sizzle selector engine](http://sizzlejs.com/) which provides great CSS support for selectors in javascript libraries. This means that the syntax used into jQuery selectors can be the same used in CSS.

So if what you want is to select an element with both .test and .color-picker classes, the correct way to do this with jQuery would be:

```
$('.test.color-picker')
```